# "Size of tensor a must match size of tensor b" - When using transformer pipelines in Python?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on a bot which can scrape data from posts on a website then categorize the comments on the posts as positive or negative (good or bad). Hence I am using the `transformers.pipeline` Python library to perform sentiment analysis on these comments.

Currently, I have made a function to sentiment the comments and then I am parsing the comments into a buffer (list) for which I can then use the sentiment function. However upon doing so I get a "RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (734) must match the size of tensor b (512) at non-singleton dimension 1" ? However from the sentiment function, I am only grabbing the score of the sentiment..

Portion of my code is below:

```
def sentiment(self, buffer):
    sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
    prediction = sentiment_pipeline(buffer)
    feed = [prediction[i]["score"] for i in range(len(buffer))]
    print("Feed : ", feed)
    return feed
```

In other method:

```
for post in subreddit_channel.hot(limit=self.samples): # for every post
      ....
      for comment in post.comments: # for every comment
            if hasattr(comment, "body"):
                comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
                print("-------------------------------")
                print("Comment: " + str(comment.body))
      buffer = [comment.body.lower() for comment in post.comments if hasattr(comment,"body")]
      post_feed.append(stats.mean(self.sentiment(buffer))) ## WHERE THE ERROR IS
      i += 1
    time.sleep(5)
    print("\n", post_feed)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!